# Bing Maps Geocode Creators Update

Tags: uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

Since the Creators Update, results from using the UWP Bing Maps API for geocoding and reverse geocoding have significantly changed.  Locations that used to be found are now not and the addresses have values in different properties.  I can run the same application on different machines with and without the Creators Update to see the differences.  These addresses are in the UK, are anyone else experiencing this issue or have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to be expected. Previous versions of the UWP maps used data primarily from a single data provider and had a lot of issues. The creators update now uses the Bing Maps data source which has data from hundreds of data providers around the world. The forward and reverse geocoding quality globally in the UWP maps has improved significantly. However, the UK is still a work in progress. The Bing Maps team has been rolling out a new geocoder which is a lot of improvements, but hasn't yet enabled this for the UK yet as they are working through some known issues. This will likely be enabled in a few months time once these issues are worked through. Currently the geocoder for the UK is using the Bing Maps geocoder which is still better than what the UWP map control was using, but the data is older.

Comment: The odd thing is the data appears to have got worse since the Creators Update